# Weird behaviour on case object equality test on Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pattern-matching

I am seeing something funny here when comparing case objects after they go through a RDD. The code is very simple.

```
trait Foo

case object Gee extends Foo
case object Bar extends Foo

val ys = List(Gee, Gee, Bar)
val xs = sc.parallelize(List(Gee, Gee, Bar))
```

Now this is weird.

```
xs.filter { x => x == Gee }.collect
```

Gives

```
res: Array[Product with Serializable with Foo] = Array()
```

While

```
ys.filter { x => x == Gee }
```

gives

```
res: List[Product with Serializable with Foo] = List(Gee, Gee)
```

Comment: Are you defining your case objects inside a class?

Comment: zero323 correctly marked this as a duplicate.